# karate mobile testing with a real device, not an emulator. I can't connect to a real device

Tags: appium, karate

```
 @android_sample_test
 Feature:  Simple test with appium

 Scenario: launch chrome in appium
     * configure driver =
     """
     {
       type: 'android',
       webDriverPath : "/wd/hub",
       start: true,
       httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }
     }
     """
     * def desiredConfig =
     """
     {
     "app":"/home/yabesh/Downloads/UiDemo.apk",
     "newCommandTimeout" : 300,
     "platformVersion" : "9.0",
     "platformName" : "Android",
     "connectHardwareKeyboard" : true,
     "deviceName" : "emulator-554",
     "avd": "Galaxy_Nexus_API_33",
     "automationName" : "UiAutomator2",
     }
    """
    * driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
    * delay(5000).screenshot()
    * delay(2500)
    * close()
```

This is my test case for android. It works in android emulator. It works on avd not adb. I don't know how to connect a real device through (usb debugging or wifi debugging). Need help